# Lookup primary keys in multiple tables

Tags: sas

the problem I'm solving has many simple solutions but what I need is to find the way to reduce the time and memory needed for the process.

On the one side I have a table with a few hundred ID's and on the other 40 monthly tables and counting. 
Each of the tables has between 500 000 to 1 mln records each for unique id. Each table has few thoustand variables but i only need 10-20 of them.

I need to lookup the tables to find the latest table when particular id from base table occur and get variable values that I need.
The newest month table is being calculated every day so many id's from previous months may occur again so I cannot just create indexed dictionary (last.id and variables) once. Also I can't afford creating new dictionary based on all tables every day.

[Visual description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mCTd.png)

I came up with some ideas but I need your help to find the most efficient concept:

1. Concatenate all monthly tables with variables needed, sort ascending ID and month, select last.id using data step. Use join or merge with base table.
   Problem: too much memory needed to set all tables. 
   Alternatively I used proc append in loop. Unfortunately not very time and memory efficient.
2. Inner join with all of the tables separately in loop:
   Low memory use but very time consuming.
3. Create dictionary based on all months besides the latest and update it every day. 
   Problem: Large dictionary table.

Now I'm looking for smart concepts how to solve this kind of problem. Maybe hash objects.. but how?

I would greatly appreciate it if you give me some feedback on this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If someone was to write some code to generate some dummy data based on your specs they may be able to provide a more specific answer to your question.  But without sample data it's hard to know the best way without trial and error.

Instead I've paraphrased some of my old answers into a more comprehensive list of things you can check.

Below are some ways to boost performance (roughly in order of performance improvement, YMMV):

1. Index the fields in each table that you will be joining on or using in a where clause.  Not all fields are good candidates for indexes so do a little research on how to determine this before indexing.
2. Reduce the number of rows as early in the process as possible (ie. use a where clause to get rid of anything you don't care about).
3. If the joins are still time consuming, consider replacing them with hash table lookups.
4. Compression. When you build the datasets make sure you use the compress=yes option if you're not already. This will shrink the size of the table on disk resulting in less disk I/O (the slowest part of querying).
5. If the steps are IO intensive, consider using views rather than creating temporary tables.
6. Make sure you are using proc append to append datasets together to reduce IO (sounds like you are, just adding this for completeness). Append the smaller dataset to the larger dataset.  Alternatively use a view to 'append' them without duplicating overhead.
7. Limit the columns you are processing by using a keep statement (reduces IO).
8. Check column lengths - make sure you're not using a field length of $255 to store something that only needs a length of $20 etc...
9. Use the SAS SPDE (Scalable Performance Data Engine). It allows you to partition your SAS datasets into multiple files and optionally spread them across different disks. Once your SAS datasets reach a certain size you can see performance improvements. I generally tend to use SPD libnames any time a dataset grows > 10G. No additional SAS modules are requires - this is enabled as part of Base SAS.